# Selenium, Python, django rest frame work not wokrin on IIS

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, iis

I am developing an application with Reactjs, Python Django rest framework api, and  selenium. I have a special requirement where I am asking captcha from user and feed it to the website. I am running selenium with api and hosted the API on IIS. It worked perfectly on local env but not working ON IIS. API end point give 500 internal server error. I have tried Selenium grid but it still doesn't work.

I tried Selenium Grid.
Try to log Selenium error and Python exception handling but not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As there are many posts around the internet containing outdated information about Python/IIS, you might simply use the wrong hosting method. So, edit the question to reveal what you did.

Comment: The first step is to check the logs on the IIS server to see if any specific errors are reported. This can give you clues as to what might be going wrong. Try using FRT to view details about the 500 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis